# Servlet and jsp, Error displaying list of images from a local directory

Tags: java, servlets

I have a local directory which contains some images. I am trying to display the list of images from the local directory but nothing is displayed. I am getting the error exception handling message that the directory is empty.I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```html
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List imgUrlList = new ArrayList();
        File imageDir = new File("/images");
        File[] files=imageDir.listFiles();

        if(files!=null) {
            for (File imageFile : files) {
                String imageFileName = imageFile.getName();
                imgUrlList.add(imageFileName);
 }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("directory is empty");
        }
        req.setAttribute("imgUrlList", imgUrlList);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test/test.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);

    }
```

```html
<c:forEach var="img" items="${imgUrlList}"> <img > </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Does it exist? Check the full path of the directory. `System.out.println(imageDir.toAbsolutePath())`

Comment: the images directory within the project directory

Comment: okay i change the directory path to File imageDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/images")); now but i think my got my JSP tag wrong because it not displaying on jsp. in my jsp i have <c:forEach var="img" items="${imgUrlList}">
    <img >
  
</c:forEach>